# How do you edit your htaccess and mod_rewrite to remove the file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First, I am on a GoDaddy server.  I know this is important, because I've viewed a ton of other questions like this.

So, I am trying to make the file extensions disappear on all my site URLS. So, the page:
www.mydomain.com/somepage.php
...would just change into...
www.mydomain.com/somepage

Or, if the page was in a directory, it would also just remove the extension...
www.mydomain.com/somedir/someotherpage.php
...would just change into...
www.mydomain.com/somedir/someotherpage

I looked around and found everyone recommending that I change my .htaccess to something like this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work. When I go to www.mydomain.com/somedir/somepage, I get redirected to my 404 page.  (but the regular PHP page works fine  www.mydomain.com/somedir/somepage.php with it's extension )

Can someone help?

I've looked through alot of these types of questions, and have tried multiple answers ... but can't get it to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried it. That did not work. 
I was originally following many online tutorials, all of which say to use "Options -MultiViews". For example: 
http://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy

Comment: Which URI did you try to test it? Did you enter: `/somedir/somepage`?

Comment: `+MultiViews` is alternate of `mod-rewrite`. If `+MultiViews` doesn't work for you I will suggest a `mod-rewrite` based solution.

Comment: Closer....

Now, when I go to www.mydomain.com/somedir/somepage.php ... I get redirected to the URL  www.mydomain.com/somedir/somepage ... but I get a 404 error. So, it is rewriting the url ... but not showing the php page.

Comment: In which directory have you placed this .htaccess? What is your DOCUMEN_ROOT?

Comment: In the root level of the server. The revised htaccess made most of the pages of my site 404 error pages, So I had to remove the file from the server.

Comment: Week this is fully tested and working code. It just expects that. htaccess file and all php files are in DOCUMEN_ROOT

Comment: So, how come the pages are showing up as 404 pages, instead of their PHP pages? The PHP page exists ... So www.mydomain.com/somedir/someotherpage.php rewrites the url to www.mydomain.com/somedir/someotherpage but shows a 404 page. It should be showing the content of www.mydomain.com/somedir/someotherpage.php

Comment: Most likely you have some local mis configuration. I have made another edit meanwhile that you can try.

Comment: Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess? OR any other .htaccess anywhere in the system?